# how can I acces nested pair in a vector by iterator?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

i am trying to access the nested pair in vector by iterator, but i am getting error in codeblock IDE, please help me how to do that ? You can see my code in the attached picture.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namestace std;

vector<pair<int , pair<int, bool> > > graph[1000000];
vector<pair<int , pair<int, bool> > >:: iterator it;

queue<int> Q;
int cost[1000000], visit[1000000];


void BFS(int s)
{
    Q.push(s)
    visit[s] = 1;
    while(!Q.empty() {
        int v = Q.front();
        Q.pop();
        for (it=graph[v].begin(); it != graph[v].end(); it++) {
            if(cost[it->first] == -1) {
                cost[it->first] = it->second->first + cost[v];
                Q.push(it->first);

            }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

```
it->first.second
```

Since it is a pointer but the pair it points is the pair itself and not a pointer.